# Select tab by index Midori

Tags: midori

Is it possible to bind `ctrl+N` to `select the N'th tab`, like it's done in Chrome/Firefox?

I tried with the `Customize Shortcuts` extension without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Method:

1. Get [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com)
2. After you install, go to your Desktop, right click > New AutoHotKey script
3. Window Key+R, In the window that pops up, type notepad and press enter
4. Navigate to your Desktop, Select the file you created
5. [Click here](http://pastebin.com/69nLmcPN), copy, then paste the text at the end of the notepad window
6. Ctrl+S, then double click the file

To switch tabs, Press Ctrl and the number of tabs you want to skip.